# Can I use different instance types for master and slave nodes without any issues when creating Amazon EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, ec2-ami

I have investigated that I can create an EMR cluster using different instance types for slave and master nodes via Java, i.e.

```
 RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
 .withMasterInstanceType("m3.large")
.withSlaveInstanceType("m3.xlarge")
```

But it is not possible to do this via AWS Console. There I can choose only one instance type for both slave nodes and master node.
I wonder why Amazon has disabled this option in AWS Console and will I face any issues if I will choose different types of instances, i.e m3.xlarge for the master node and m3.large for the slave nodes?

[Screenshot from my AWS Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1jVc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify a different instance type for master and core nodes via the AWS Console. You need to click on "Go to advanced options" when creating a cluster